# Should we replace [factory-girl] with [factory-bot]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The gem previously known as [factory-girl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-girl) has been [renamed](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/NAME.md) to [factory-bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-bot). Should we replace the former with the latter?

Please don't comment on thoughtbot's decision to rename the gem.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of a punny title. I love them as much as anyone else, but considering that some people were offended by "factory girl", I decided to not try to be funny with the title.

Comment: If the name of the tech is changed it makes sense to rename the tag in my head. The tag-name should surely reflect the name of the thing it was made to describe? If the government decided to rename my street I wouldn't keep giving the old address to cab drivers.

Comment: My thought(bot) is if has been renamed by the owner, that would be a major factor(y) in deciding to rename it here as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[factory-girl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-girl) has been renamed and syn'd to [factory-bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-bot).

I copied across the tag wiki but it contains some references to factory-girl so if someone wants to do an edit to tidy it up that'd be great.

Answer (score 4):

The tag should probably be renamed to use the current name of the gem, [factory-bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-bot). For completeness' sake, the tag's info should probably mention the old name (possibly with the link you included) and the old [factory-girl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory-girl) tag should be kept as a tag synonym to the new tag to make navigation easier for people still using older versions.